# nginx.conf file gets reset automatically on Elasticbeanstalk EC2 Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my Rails app on AWS Elasticbeanstalk and the app allows the user
to upload videos so in my nginx.conf file which is in etc/nginx directory in EC2
Instance I have to add a line in server part to avoid the error `"Nginx: 413 Request Entity Too Large Error"`:

> client_max_body_size 999M;
>   and then service nginx reload

But after uploading 10-15 videos this file gets reset and then I have to again add 
this line and the IP of EC2 Instance also changes,

Can someone Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your instance is being terminated and rebuilt. Can you check the "Events" page for your environment and see if that's happening? That should be the only reason the filesystem is reset and the IP address is changing. I suspect an auto-scaling rule is being triggered.

As to why the file is being reset, have you ever noticed the following warning that gets displayed every time you connect via `eb ssh`:

```
This EC2 instance is managed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Changes made via
SSH WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by auto-scaling.
```

At least with the Ruby+Passenger platform, EB generates the nginx configuration files from templates that are found at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf` - you should see files called `nginx_config.erb` and `nginx_config_healthd.erb`.

You can use EB extensions (described in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)) to modify those files during a deploy, which will ensure that your changes persist through auto-scaling. Your extension might look something like this:

**.ebextensions/01-edit-nginx-conf.config**

```
container_commands:
  01backup_nginx_config:
    command: "cp -n /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb.original"
  02edit_nginx_config:
    command: "sh -c \"sed '/passenger_ruby/ i \
\             client_max_body_size 999M;' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb.original > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb\""
```